# rpc json outside localhost

Tags: json-rpc, daemon

I tried to to host bitcoin core json-rpc to listen other than localhost but it would not work even i set it to listen to ip 0.0.0.0

My config (for bitcoin.conf)

```
testnet=1
server=1
daemon=1
listen=1
rpcuser=something
rpcpassword=secret
rpcport=8332
rpcconnect=0.0.0.0
```

So how do i make it so that it will listen to ip other than localhost or 127.0.0.1?

VPS informations:

Ubuntu 16.04

Latest Core (just installed it today)

client is remote

Comment: Some more details could help, such as operating system, where are you running the client, which version, etc.

Comment: Alright:

Ubuntu 16.04

Latest Version (just installed it today)

Client is over internet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listen` option is for the P2P network connection, not the RPC service.

---

The option you want is `rpcallowip=<ip>`. To allow all IP addresses to connect to your node's RPC port, you can use `rpcallowip=0.0.0.0`. Note that doing so is not recommended as it is insecure.

---

Don't set `rpcconnect` as that will make it impossible for `bitcoin-cli` to interact with Bitcoin Core.

Comment: `rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0`